# Почему теряется указатель на объект?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

При создании динамического объекта в методе, я хочу сохранить указатель в мапу (на случай повторного использования) и вернуть его. Возвращается он всегда правильно, но в случае использования emplace, в мапе он почему-то теряется и в следующем обращении, создается заново. А при записи по ключу все отлично работает. (код прилагаю)

Почему так происходит? Где теряется указатель?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CTest
{
public:
    CTest()
        :m_map()
    {}

    ~CTest()
    {
        for (auto& item : m_map)
        {
            delete item.second;
        }
    }

    int* GetValue(int i)
    {
        int* result = m_map[i];

        if (result == nullptr)
        {
            result = new int(i);
            m_map[i] = result;          // works good
            //m_map.emplace(i, result); // doesn't work
        }
        return result;
    }
private:
    map<int, int*> m_map;
};

int main()
{
    CTest c;

    cout << *c.GetValue(2) << endl;
    cout << *c.GetValue(3) << endl;
    cout << *c.GetValue(2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Между `operator[]` и `insert`/`emplace` есть одна важная разница. `operator[]`, если элемент уже есть, заменяет его. А вот `insert`/`emplace` ничего не делают. Когда в самом начале функции Вы вызываете `[]`, элемент уже создан...

**UPD**

мой, понятный вариант функции GetValue

```
int* GetValue(int i)
{
    auto it = m_map.find(i); // поищем его

    if (it == m_map.end()) // если его нет
    {
        // создадим. emplace возвращает нам пару, в которой первый элемент - нужный нам итератор.
        it = m_map.emplace(i, new int(i)).first;
    }
    // этот итератор содержит либо существующий элемент, либо созданный.
    return it->second;
}
```

emplace вторым элементом пары возвращает признак успешности вставки. Можно было конечно сделать на базе этого (втиснув `emplace` прям в `if`), но тогда что делать с созданным элементом? его нужно удалять (ответ user7860670 этого как раз это не учитывает. Да, если использовать умные указатели, память почистится, но лишнее создание-удаление объекта (который может быть ну очень тяжелым на создание) может свести такую хитрую конструкцию в ответе (которая пытается выглядеть супер оптимизированной) в ноль).

Но если уж заморачиваться на скорость, то можно перейти на emplace_hint. Оно первым параметром получает указатель на "предполагаемое место вставки". И если с ним угадать, то вставка может быть ну очень быстрой (по документации - амортизированная константная).

```
int* GetValue(int i)
{
    auto it = m_map.lower_bound(i);

    if (it == m_map.end() || it->first != i)
    {
        it = m_map.emplace_hint(it, i, new int(i));
    }
    return it->second;
}
```

Конечно, нужно смотреть, как именно создается объект, который вставляется в мапу, может это все перевернет.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном коде вставка в контейнер происходит на строке `int* result = m_map[i];` так как оператор [] всегда будет вставлять в контейнер новый элемент, если его еще нет. Соответственно последующий emplace добавлять ничего не будет. Вместо этого следует сначала иcпользовать `find`

```
auto p_item{m_map.find(key)};
if (m_map.end() == p_item)
{
    p_item = m_map.emplace(::std::piecewise_construct, ::std::forward_as_tuple(key), ::std::forward_as_tuple(value)).first;
}
return p_item->second;
```

Также в контейнере не следует хранить сырые указатели.

Comment: вот зачем так усложнять... никогда не понимал

Comment: @KoVadim это вы про что?

Comment: о коде в ответе

Comment: @KoVadim А что с ним не так?

Comment: ок, делаем рекурсию. читайте мой первый комментарий.

Comment: @KoVadim так а что в приведенном коде не устраивает? если знаете как проще написать эквивалентный код - то приведите